# No Lightning Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The term "Lightning" is a broad brand comprising many different technologies.

How do we approach this as a community especially when it includes:

**UI**
 - Lightning Component Framework
 - Lightning App Builder
 - Lightning Extensions (coming)

**Backend Services**
 - Lightning Connect

**Tools**
 - Lightning Process Builder
 - Lightning Schema Builder
 - Lightning Communities Builder

For the first time, I saw this tag appear today, which, if you ask me, is not useful for categorizing anything.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning

Answer (score 9):

Agreed - lightning as a tag in itself is about as useful as salesforce! I think the natural way is

- [lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components)
- [lightning-connect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-connect)
- [lightning-app-builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-app-builder)
- [lightning-extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-extensions)

etc. In fact, you can already see questions on the first two tags.

If we see other tags, edit them, or, if they seem to be prevalent, create synonyms. After a while, folks will catch on, I think.

What sort of questions were tagged lightning? I can create an alias to lightning-components if that what people are using it for.